# Where can I find a comprehensive list of DOSbox shortcut commands, not hosted by dosbox.com?

Tags: dosbox

The website http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/ is down. So I can't access the help files. I also cannot find anything else on creating shortcuts for dosbox... anything anywhere.

specifically shortcuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teun has the right idea. Unfortunately the Google Cache does not present clickable links (they all go to the downed site).

However, you could also use the [Internet Archive WayBackMachine](http://archive.org/web/):

The last snapshot for `dosbox.com/wiki` is from October 30th:

http://web.archive.org/web/20131101024322/http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Main_Page

The links on these pages are clickable and stay within the WayBackMachine so you can browse the whole site.

Comment: As soon as I saw it I was able to get what I wanted. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google's webcache at http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.dosbox.com/wiki/